# Pluralized Rest Resources

Tags: java, rest, architecture, api-design

I want to create a new rest resources that searches an entity in database. I have to make the request as POST since there is a complex criteria passed in a request body.

I created my resource endpoint as /search, however, I learned that resources should be always pluralized. In this case, should I be naming as /searches? I want to know if /searches is a standard naming convention?

Answer (score 2):

No, I have never heard that resources should always be pluralized. I would say /search is appropriate here. For example, if you do a search on google or msn, you'll see that they use /search for their searches.

Hopefully this helps.